# Trouble with drag-and-drop sortable list using ReactJs and react-dnd

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, reactjs

## Using [ReactJs](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [react-dnd](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd)

I want a user to be able to sort the form fields (a.k.a. `properties`)

I set up the code almost identical to the [source code](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/_sortable-simple) for the Cards in the [simple sort demo](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/#/sortable-simple). There are no console warnings or errors, and I can't figure out why this won't work. I can neither drag nor drop anything.

### What it looks like:

[image: Example dummy-seeded form]

## Code:

### App.js

```js
import EditForm from './Forms/EditForm.js';

var id = $('#form').data('id');
var source = `/api/forms/${id}?include=type,properties.type`;

React.render(
    <EditForm source={source} />,
    document.getElementById('form')
);
```

### EditForm.js

```js
import React from 'react/addons';
import update from 'react/lib/update';
import Property from './Property.js';

var EditForm = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ React.addons.LinkedStateMixin ],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            id: null,
            name: null,
            slug: null,
            properties: []
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.getFormFromServer();
    },

    getFormFromServer: function () {
        $.get(this.props.source, (result) => {
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    id: result.id,
                    name: result.name,
                    slug: result.slug,
                    properties: result.properties.data
                });
            }
        });
    },

    moveProperty: function(id, afterId) {
        const { properties } = this.state;

        const property = properties.filter(p => p.id === id)[0];
        const afterProperty = properties.filter(p => p.id === afterId)[0];
        const propertyIndex = properties.indexOf(property);
        const afterIndex = properties.indexOf(afterProperty);

        this.setState(update(this.state, {
            properties: {
                $splice: [
                    [propertyIndex, 1],
                    [afterIndex, 0, property]
                ]
            }
        }));
    },

    render: function() {
        const { properties } = this.state;

        var propertiesList = properties.map((property, i) => {
            return (
                <Property
                    key={property.id}
                    id={property.id}
                    type={property.type.name}
                    name={property.name}
                    moveProperty={this.moveProperty} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Form</h1>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" valueLink={this.linkState('name')} className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Properties:</label>
                        <div className="list-group properties-list">
                            {propertiesList}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

export default EditForm;
```

### Property.js

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react/addons';
import { DragDropMixin } from 'react-dnd';
import ItemTypes from './ItemTypes';

const dragSource = {
    beginDrag(component) {
        return {
            item: {
                id: component.props.id
            }
        };
    }
};

const dropTarget = {
    over(component, item) {
        component.props.moveProperty(item.id, component.props.id);
    }
};

var Property = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ React.addons.LinkedStateMixin, DragDropMixin ],

    propTypes: {
        id: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
        type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        moveProperty: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },

    statics: {
        configureDragDrop(register) {
            register(ItemTypes.PROPERTY, {
                dragSource,
                dropTarget
            });
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        const { type } = this.props;
        const { name } = this.props;
        const { isDragging } = this.getDragState(ItemTypes.PROPERTY);
        const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;

        return (
            <a  className="list-group-item"
                {...this.dragSourceFor(ItemTypes.PROPERTY)}
                {...this.dropTargetFor(ItemTypes.PROPERTY)}>
                {type}: {name}
            </a>
        );
    }
});

export default Property;
```

### ItemTypes.js

```js
module.exports = {
    PROPERTY: 'property'
};
```

If anybody could help I would greatly appreciate it. It's kind of sad how much time I've actually spent trying to figure this out.

#### Reference links:

- [My code on github](https://github.com/SevenShores/Kraken/tree/ab4c98e2bb3caa30c50fbd7b0979a082e848fd81/resources/assets/jsx/Forms)
- [Demo example](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/#/sortable-simple)
- [Demo source on github](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/_sortable-simple)

Comment: Would you mind adding the unminified code to a JSBin? Makes it easier to play around with and see what's happening.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl I tried, but it's not showing up... might be because of ES6 stuff or what, I'm not sure...  http://jsbin.com/vucuji/1/edit?html,js,output  edit:  ugh looks like my html disappeared -_-;;

Comment: There is a fiddle here. I got it to render but only when JSX is transformed already: http://jsfiddle.net/fungku/u88kxbvk/

Comment: That code chunk is pretty huge. Could you use JSBin instead? It offers JSX support. And please only include the code needed to see the issue, add libraries as script tags.

Comment: After I don't even want to know how many hours of pulling out my hair, it is [fixed](https://github.com/SevenShores/Kraken/commit/397a3486fa07e4019face32be591340aca7859bb)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending over a day trying to get the drag and drop working I fixed it with [one single line of code](https://github.com/SevenShores/Kraken/commit/397a3486fa07e4019face32be591340aca7859bb).

```js
import React from 'react/addons';
```

How it compiled and rendered at all without that, I don't even know.